# CSS: Why are my media queries not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

My CSS Queries are this

```
<!-- CSS files for responsive side of site -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1900px)" href="../Assets/CSS/Responsive1920.css">
 <!-- 1900 or less -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1900px) and (min-width: 1800px)" href="../Assets/CSS/Responsive1800.css">
```

This doesn't seem to be working. They've been working for months and now all of a sudden they don't. I haven't made any changes to this either. File path is correct too.

Comment: Do you have your meta tag included like this : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: yes `include("../Assets/JavaScript/scripts.php"); ?><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` this is what i have on my home page. Scripts.php has the code in original post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen size condition looks strict, try this and you will see the difference at size 1900px:

```html
<!-- CSS files for responsive side of site -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1900px)" href="../Assets/CSS/Responsive1920.css">
 <!-- 1900 or less -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1900px)" href="../Assets/CSS/Responsive1800.css">
```

Comment: (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1900px) it means your css only apply for screen size from 1900px to 1920px => very little right?, so try to use min-width or max-width only

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code as per below:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1900px) and (max-width: 1920px)' href='../Assets/CSS/Responsive1920.css' />

    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 1900px)' href='../Assets/CSS/Responsive1800.css' />
```